# Table changes document

Tags: tables

There is something wrong with this table and I don't know what. Latex marks the "&" in the last rows. Says something like "more columns than specified in the table." The error changes the whole document as the text isn't aligned anymore afterwards. So if someone could help, it would be really appreciated!

```
\centering
\scalebox{1}{\begin{tabular}{cc@{}c@{}c@{}}
        %
        %& & \multicolumn{2}{c}{General 2} \\
        %
        & & {\small a} & {\small b} \\ \cline{3-4}
        %
        & {\small a} \ & \vline \hfill \ 3,3 \ \hfill \vline & \hfill \ 4,4 \ \hfill \vline \\ \cline{3-4}
        %
        & {\small b} \ & \vline \hfill \ 4,4 \ \hfill \vline & \hfill \ 1,1 \ \hfill \vline \\ \cline{3-4}
        %
\end{tabular}}
\newline
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  If I add a documentclass as well as the required packages, I end up with a code that compiles perfectly fine and does not result in the error message you describe. Therefore, please preapare such a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the error message you get.

Comment: Entirely unrelated, but what's the purpose of all the `\vline \hfill` commands? Wouldn't it be easier to use something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\mymc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small #1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\small}c|c|c|}
 \mymc{} & \mymc{a} & \mymc{b} \\ \cline{2-3}
 a  & 3,3 & 4,4 \\ \cline{2-3}
 b  & 4,4 & 1,1 \\ \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}` to get at least a very similar output?